# How to blur an image across browsers?

Tags: css, image, firefox, google-chrome, blur

In Chrome, the below CSS blurs the image.  However when I view the images in firefox, the image is no longer blurred.  Any advice on how to get it to work across browsers?

```
div.wrapper{
    float:left; /* important */
    position:relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */ 
    padding: 5px;
}

div.imageblur{
    position: relative; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 320px; 
    filter: blur(5px);
       -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
       -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
       -ms-filter: blur(5px);

   margin:-1px;
   padding:1px;
}

div.image_container{
   width:318px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

## html

```
<div class="wrapper">

            <!-- image -->
            <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">

                <div class="image_container">
                    <div class="imageblur">     
                        <a href="youtube/IiGW9JA_aPg"> <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/IiGW9JA_aPg/hqdefault.jpg"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <!-- end image div -->

</div>
```

Comment: A hint about browser vendor prefixes: Include the non-vendored css rule last.

Answer (score 0):

That's because webkit is the only one that supports `filter`. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

See also: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

Answer (score 0):

Filter is supported is Firefox too but with a slightly complex syntax: Here is a sample example I out on fiddle:

```
img{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

[**FILTER EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xDJzU/7/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS filters are very new, therefore there is little support. Safari (nightly) and Chrome support it exclusively at the moment because of webkit.